# Using Hashmap with POI libraries in Selenium

Tags: java, excel, selenium, hashmap, apache-poi

I have an xlsx file which contains all the locators to be used in my script. [Excel SnapShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LABAD.jpg)

Now to use the Locator and its value I would be using a hashmap. Can someone please help me how to put these values in a hashmap and call them in my selenium script. I have somehow managed to read the excel using POI libraries however not able to figure out how to put them in a hashmap and where to add the cell and rows in hashmap. Also how to call them in my selenium script.

```
public void readValueFromExcel()
    {
        Iterator<Row> rowiterator=shSheet.iterator();
        while (rowiterator.hasNext())
            {
            HashMap<String, String> xHashmap = new HashMap();
            Row nextRow = rowiterator.next();
            Iterator<Cell> celliterator= nextRow.cellIterator();
                while (celliterator.hasNext())
                    {
                    Cell nextCell = celliterator.next();
                    switch (nextCell.getCellType())
                        {
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                        System.out.print(nextCell.getStringCellValue());
                        break;
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                        System.out.print(nextCell.getBooleanCellValue());
                        break;
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                        System.out.print(nextCell.getNumericCellValue());
                        break;
                        }
                    //System.out.print(" - ");

                    }
                //System.out.println();

            }
```

Comment: You have three columns in given excel sheet but declared HashMap<Key,Value> xHashMap can hold only two column. So how are you planing to put the values ?

Comment: Hi I am planning to take the first two columns in a hashmap.

Comment: you should declare the HashMap out of row iterator and statement  put(key,value), out of cell iterator. Have two variable like String key and String value, set appropriate key and value in case statement and out of cell iterator have something like xHashmap.put(key,value). In essence for each row iteration you will have one entrySet() of xHashmap. Your method should return Map object for re-usability of HashMap.